# How to get categories from a database for highcharts using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

I am trying to retrieve categories for highcharts from a database. The categories are simply months that correspond to the data in the chart.

**Model function**

```
function getMonthlySumOrders()
{
    $this->db->select("SUM(price_each*quantity) AS sum_monthly_price, DATE_FORMAT(job.order_date, '%M') AS 'order_date', customer.company_name", false);
    $this->db->join('job', 'job.job_id = job_details.job_id');
    $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.company_id = job.company_id');
    $this->db->where('job.company_id', '6');
    $this->db->where('job.order_date >=', date("m"));
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(job.order_date)');
    $this->db->order_by("job.order_date", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(4);
    $query = $this->db->get('job_details');

return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('customer_model');
}

function index(){

$data = $this->customer_model->getMonthlySumOrders();

foreach ($data as $order_sum_array) {
            $order_sum['sum_monthly_price'][] = $order_sum_array['sum_monthly_price'];
            $categories['month'][] = $order_sum_array['order_date'];
        }

$order_sum_data[] = array('name' => 'Company', 'data' => $order_sum['sum_monthly_price']);
$categories_data[] = $categories['month'];
$this->view_data['order_sum_data'] = json_encode($order_sum_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$this->view_data['categories_data'] = json_encode($categories_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$this->load->view('chart', $this->view_data);
}
```

**View script**

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Orders'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
    categories: <?php echo $categories_data ;?>
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Orders'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series:  <?php echo $order_sum_data ;?>
});
});
    </script>
```

So the data for the chart '$order_sum_data' works and displays on the chart but the categories all get put into the first bar of the chart.
If I echo $order_sum_data . $categories_data I get:

```
[{"name":"Company","data":[12209.8,2490,5109,4065]}]  [["September","August","July","June"]]
```

I can see that there are two square brackets around the categories but don't know how to reduce that to one set which is required.

I also require the company name, which I have selected in my model, to be attached to the order_sum array name component. Where it is just hard coded as 'Company' at the moment.

On a separate issue my query won't display 0 if there are no orders that particular month, how would I arrange an if statement to display a 0 height column if no results found for a particular month with the corresponding month category?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Categories issue:

- you have an array of arrays: `[["September","August","July","June"]]`, while should be just an array: `["September","August","July","June"]`

0-value issue:

- use [`minPointLength`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.minPointLength) option to display bars where value=0.

Company name:

- since you know where it's hardcoded, then why just you replace that value with some variable which will have information about the company name?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I have gotten a bit more since I posted the question. But thought I may be heading in the wrong direction still, so posted a question on the highcharts forum. Although they suggested that it wasn't a highcharts issue my current code is still on the post if your able to have a look please. [link]http://forum.highcharts.com/post109313.html#p109313 The issue seems to be that I don't receive any value from my query if it's null which I require to be 0. Could this be the minPointLength you suggested?

Comment: No it's not. If you don't have value as they said, then nothing will be displayed. You need to add somehow that value.